# What is the significance of $L^2$ space over other spaces($L^p$) for numerical analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, numerical-methods

Why do we mostly work in $L^2$ space?

There is a theorem stating that

> Prove the dual space of $l^p$ is isomorphic to $l^q$ if $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$

If we choose $p=2$ we see that the dual space of $l^2$ is isomorphic to $l^2$. But I do not exactly know what is the use of this isomorphism? Does it have any sort of significance numerically?

Comment: Every Hilbert space is isomorphic to its own dual. So to have a useful notion of inner product, you need the space to be isomorphic to its own dual. I don't know enough about numerical analysis to know why this is important, but if I had to guess, then I'd say that this is the important point here.

Comment: I think the better question is: Why would we ever work outside of $L^1, L^2$ or $L^\infty$. Have you run across a case where you needed to work in $L^{3/2}$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts That's also a good question.

Comment: I gather that my reply is not what you where looking for. Would you add a few words about your actual needs?

Answer (score 1):

The $L^2$ vector spaces are useful for practical work precisely because they are inner product spaces. If $V \subseteq W$ is a finite dimensional subspace of an inner product space $W$, then we can with ease compute the orthogonal projection $v$ of any vector $x$ onto finite dimensional subspace $V$. The abstract algorithm is the Gram-Schmidt method and the practical realization is the QR-factorization algorithm. The orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $V$ is the vector $v \in V$ which is closest to $x$ with respect to the $2$-norm. It is much more difficult to find the optimal approximation with respect to say the $1$-norm or the $\infty$-norm.